# how to convert Collection<? extends ObjectFrame> to map

Tags: java, collections, robotics

I am working with industrial robot controller based on OS that utilize java for programming(KUKA IIWA robot) Company that develops software provides custom libraries for robot programming.

I have a method called loadAllFrames() that returns(picture shows javadoc for that method):

```
Collection<? extends ObjectFrame>
```

[javadoc for loadAllFrames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN2Jh.jpg)

The .toString output looks like this:

```
[nullBase [X=0.00 Y=0.00 Z=0.00 A=0.00 B=0.00 C=0.00], 
StartProcess [X=778.16 Y=89.64 Z=699.38 A=1.15 B=1.56 C=-1.97], 
appRightCoupon [X=703.49 Y=181.64 Z=649.39 A=1.05 B=1.55 C=-2.12]]
```

This information is parsed from .xml file.
I need to get this information and store it in some usable data structure.

From my perspective this looks like match for map (for example: `map<String, ObjectFrame>`) where String will be *nullBase* and ObjectFrame is *[X=0.00 Y=0.00 Z=0.00 A=0.00 B=0.00 C=0.00]*

Question is how I can do that?
How to convert this `Collection<? extends ObjectFrame>` to map.

At this point this is too advanced topic for me. I am reading on maps and collections but can't get a good understanding on what I need to do here. So far I got something like that:

```
 Collection<? extends ObjectFrame> test1Collection = defaultDataSource.loadAllFrames();
 test1dumpFile.println(test1Collection.toString());
```

Which gave me output presented above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can utilize a `Stream` for this, but no one will be able to help because you need to provide the getter-methods for the `String` and `ObjectFrame` that will represent the key and value of the `Map`.

Comment: I see what you saying about lack of getters. I needed inspiration on how to proceed and I get it from answers below. thx

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this:

```
Collection<? extends ObjectFrame> test1Collection = defaultDataSource.loadAllFrames();

Map<String, Object> asMap = new HashMap<>();

Object[] asArray = test1Collection.toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < asArray.length-1; i+=2) {
  String key = (String) asArray[i];
  Object value = asArray[i+1];
  asMap.put(key, value);
}
```

I used that conversion to an array; as that makes it easier to do write down that loop working on "key/value pairs".

The crucial point is that

```
  Object value = asArray[i+1];
```

Instead of just dumping each second entry as Object, you might have a much closer look, and see if you should/could build a special class to wrap around this data.

The above is just meant as an inspiration; to get you going. Neither compiled nor tested; so beware of typos or subtle errors.

Comment: So it came out that every element of the collection is ObjectFrame element.
What I don't understand is why I cannot do that:
ObjectFrame[] asArray = test1Collection.toArray();
 Please see ma answer for code that worked for me.

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7, something like:

```
  for(Item item : collection) {
      map.put(item.getSomething(), item);
  }
```

This will overwrite previous map entries if the key is a repeat, so if there are duplicates, you'll need to do something cleverer - either use a `MultiMap` from a third-party collections library, or make it a `Map<List<Item>>`, and:

```
  for(Item item : collection) {
      Something key = item.getSomething();
      List<Item> list = map.get(key);
      if(list == null) {
           list = new ArrayList<>();
           map.put(key, list);
      }
      list.add(item);
  }
```

In Java 8, there is a `Collector` ready made for the purpose:

```
 Map<Something,List<Item>> map = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getSomething));
```

Comment: OK, Thx a million. This was a key:   for(Item item : collection) 
It made me realize what I am doing here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<? extends ObjectFrame> test1Collection = defaultDataSource.loadAllFrames();
         for(ObjectFrame item : test1Collection) {
             System.out.println(item.getName());  //nullFrame
             System.out.println(item.copy());     //[X=0.00 Y=0.00 Z=0.00 A=0.00 B=0.00 C=0.00]
          }
```

Based on this code I can easly build my map if I need to. THX !